# Why isn't my SVG image appearing in my windows 10 toast?

Tags: windows-10, toast

I'm trying to create a Win10 toast notification with a hero image, but for some reason, when I try to use an SVG image, the toast doesn't have the hero notification.

I'm using XML formatted toast in a desktop application, not UWP.

Changing the src reference to a PNG or GIF image works fine; however, other answers to related questions suggest that SVG images should work.

I'd prefer to use SVG, as I don't want to worry about scaling.

My toast XML looks like this:

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>Header text</text>
            <text>Body text.</text>
            <image placement="hero" src="file:///<path>/Images/toast-hero-image.svg"/>
            <image placement="appLogoOverride" src="file:////<path>/Images/privacy-icon.svg"/>
        </binding>
    </visual>
    <actions>
        <action content="OK" activationtype="protocol" arguments="Ok"/>
        <action content="Not right now" activationtype="system" arguments="dismiss"/>
    </actions>
</toast>
```